# i am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

hi all I am trying to complete a project for my boss and i am running into an issue, each time i run the code I am getting an error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all', now i am not a python coder at all really i can just feel my way through when i need to, i have checked the backend of the page and all the div tags look right and  did a good search on the web and to my noob eyes its looks ok but i can't seem to get it to work.  I am trying to go into the page and put each of the flight details in their own element so I can save them to a MySQL database, here is the code

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mysql.connector

page = requests.get("https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
flights = soup.find(id="SearchResultFlightListTable")
flight_items = flights.find_all(class_="row")
flight = flight_items[0]
print(flight.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

All working now

```
    from requests_html import HTMLSession
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd="****",
  database="flightdata"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# create an HTML Session object
session = HTMLSession()

# Use the object above to connect to needed webpage
resp = session.get("https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/?flt_no=&carrier=All&city=&dte=Current&leg=Departures")

# Run JavaScript code on webpage
resp.html.render()


airline_spans = resp.html.find('.SearchResultFlightListRow')
airline_list = [span.text.split('\n') for span in airline_spans]

for flight in airline_list:
    if len(flight) == 7:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate, status = flight
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} and flight status is {status}')

    elif len(flight) == 6:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated, gate = flight
        status = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate {gate} and flight status is {status}')

    elif len(flight) == 5:
        flightno, From, to, scheduled, estimated = flight
        gate = 'IDEL'
        statua = 'IDEL'
        print (f'Flight no {flightno} from  {From} to {to} is scheduled to depart at {scheduled} from gate and flight status is {status} {gate}')


   sql = "INSERT INTO flightinfo (From, id, airline, to, flightno, scheduled, estimatedTime, scheduledDate, latestTime, status) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

    val = (origin, flight_id, airline, " ".join(destination), ", ".join(flightNumbers), scheduledTime, estimatedTime,
            scheduledDate, latestTime, status)
    data.append(val)


# doing a batch insert
mycursor.executemany(sql, data)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
#replace with code to add flight details to database


#print(airline_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are searching for id = `SearchResultFlightListTable` but it is a class , so that's why you were getting NoneType error
I have modified the code a bit, you can refer below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

page = requests.get("https://www.adelaideairport.com.au/flight-information/flight-search/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
flights = soup.find(class_="SearchResultFlightListTable")
flight_items = flights.find_all(class_="row")
flight = flight_items[0]
print(flight.prettify())
```

Comment: this is just showing me the code of the site mate, but thanks i got it all wokring as below